# Displaying a Number in Words in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I work on VS05 C# window .In my rdlc report i want to show my group amount in word...
like in my group i got the agount 1000 ...now i want to show that in word....but how?
I know how to convert amount in word, but problem arise when i use it on my group....how to convert group amount in word in my need .......is there any built in method like : sum,avg ,count ,date ,today .....in rdlc .......i want any built in method....

Comment: This question should be tagged with SQL-Server-Reporting-Services

Comment: maybe ....i need solution for rdlc

Comment: hope show me path that give me the solution

Answer (score 1):

With this: [Convert Numeric Figures into Words](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL+Aids/30970/), you can convert the number to words within SQL and then just have the report display the varchar string.  The report can just treat the string like regular data, like it would with a name.  You should be able to group by it, as any other column in the result set.

Comment: In report we can use the sum function ....After Sum the value ,How can i get it from SQLServer....I want to show the sum value in word ..i work on rdlc VS05....Do you help me to show report amount in word

Comment: do all the work in the SQL, just display the results in the report